# excel vba error 400 with large array (large data input / output)

Tags: vba, excel, testing, size

I wrote the below macro in Excel (2010) VBA to add markers to contracts with various issues to a master tracker.  While doing some size testing I am getting error 400 when I attempt to run with an input of 50,000 contracts (array Contracts), but it runs fine with 40,000 (took about 14 minutes).  Any ideas at why I am getting the error?  Commented in the code where it is stopping at 50,000.  Thank you!

```
Sub UploadNew()

''''''''''''''''''''''''Add All Contracts to End of Master'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'Set up the array Contracts which will house the new contracts to be uploaded
Dim Contracts() As String
Dim size As Long
Dim R As Integer
Dim N As Long

'This sets up the value for N as the end of the current master list
N = Worksheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Determine size of array and store it into variable size
size = Worksheets("Update").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

'Identifies which Remediation column to add the marker to
R = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Update").Range("F2"), Range("E14:G263"), 3, False)

'Having counted size we can redimension the array
ReDim Contracts(size)

'Insert the values in column A into the array
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To size
        Contracts(i) = Range("A1").Offset(i)
Next i

'Takes each value in the array and adds it to the end of the master list using N
For i = 1 To size

    Worksheets("Master").Range("A" & N).Value = Contracts(i)

    N = N + 1

Next i

'Remove the duplicates from the master tab based on the first column
Worksheets("Master").Range("A:ZZ").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

'Remove blank rows from Master
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & N).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.EntireRow.Delete

''''''''''''''''''''''''Add All Contracts to End of Master'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''Place New Contract Marker for Each Contract'''''''''''''''''''''''''

'This searches all the contracts in the master and places a 1 R columns to the right of
'the found contract
For i = 1 To size

    Dim rgFound As Range
    Set rgFound = Worksheets("Master").Range("A2:A" & N).Find(Contracts(i))

'! Code is stopping about here with 50,000 contracts, doesn't add a single marker !'

        With rgFound.Offset(, R)
            .Value = "1"
            .NumberFormat = "General"
        End With

Next i

'''''''''''''''''''''Place New Contract Marker for Each Contract'''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of using *Contracts* at all? It seems you laboriously load up the array cell by cell then immediately return the values to another worksheet cell by cell. Direct bulk value transfer would be virtually instantaneous.

Comment: Because the Contracts may or may not already be there with markers on other issues.  So first it adds all of the newly uploaded, removes the duplicates, then places a marker based on the selected issue.  It's meant to be used over and over to update a master issue tracker.

Comment: What is the worksheet when you do not specify a worksheet? Sometimes you explicitly refer to Master or Update; sometimes no worksheet at all.

Comment: The worksheet is Update, I had meant to add a worksheet to everything as I thought it would be faster, does it slow it down to explicitly state it?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite bulk loads and bulk unloads the array. I've swapped out a worksheet [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) for the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) since there **should** be guaranteed matches.

```
Sub UploadNew()

''''''''''''''''''''''''Add All Contracts to End of Master'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Set up the array Contracts which will house the new contracts to be uploaded
    Dim Contracts As Variant
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, R As Integer


    With Worksheets("Update")

        'Identifies which Remediation column to add the marker to
        'I have no idea why you are looking up F2 in column E (and returning value from column G) on the Updates worksheet
        R = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("F2"), .Range("E14:G263"), 3, False)

        'AT THIS POINT R SHOULD BE AN INTEGER BETWEEN 2 and 16384
        'NOT LARGER OR SMALLER OR TEXT
        'CHECK WITH A WATCH WINDOW!!!!!!!!!!!

        'Insert the values in column A into the array (SKIP HEADER ROW)
        Contracts = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2

    End With

    With Worksheets("Master")

        'This sets up the value for N as the end of the current master list
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Takes each value in the array and adds it to the end of the master list using N
        .Range("A" & N).Resize(UBound(Contracts, 1), UBound(Contracts, 2)) = Contracts

        'Remove the duplicates from the master tab based on the first column
        .Range("A:ZZ").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

        'Remove blank rows from Master
        If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Range("A2:A" & N))) Then _
            .Range("A2:A" & N).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

''''''''''''''''''''''''Add All Contracts to End of Master'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''Place New Contract Marker for Each Contract'''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'This searches all the contracts in the master and places a 1 R columns to the right of
        'the found contract
        For i = LBound(Contracts, 1) To UBound(Contracts, 1)

            With .Cells(Application.Match(Contracts(i, 1), .Columns(1), 0), R)
                .Value = "1"
                .NumberFormat = "General"
            End With

        Next i

    End With

'''''''''''''''''''''Place New Contract Marker for Each Contract'''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

btw, regarding `Dim rgFound As Range` ; do not declare a variable in a loop. Declare it outside the loop and assign it new values inside the loop.

Comment: Wow, I just learned so much.  Thank you for your help, this looks great!

Comment: I'm not sure if it should be `.Value = 1` not `.Value = "1"`. I generally believe that numbers should be numbers, not text-that-looks-like-a-number. If you have time, feel free to drop back and report any significant increase in speed/efficiency.

Comment: Good tip on the value = 1.  I ran the new code, 50,000 contracts in under 3 minutes, compared to 14 minutes for 40,000.  Did 100,000 contracts in 7 minutes 20 seconds.  It's beautiful, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to report back. It sounds like you are well on your way.